# VB.Net regex random string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have regex code that gets string between 2 strings from TextBox1.

TextBox1 looks something like this:

```
href="www.example.com/account/05798/john123">
href="www.example.com/account/4970/max16">
href="www.example.com/account/96577/killer007">
href="www.example.com/account/3077/hackerboy1337">
href="www.example.com/account/43210/king42">
```

So, it will get value from `href="www.example.com/account/4321/` to `">` (usernames)

The problem is, how to do it? My regex code:

`(?<="href=""www.example.com/account/RANDOM_STRING/")(.*?)(?="">)`

I know i could replace `RANDOM_STRING` with `\w{4}`, but some IDs are 5-digit.

Comment: You can remove the fixed substrings from the start/end and use `Split`

Comment: Or, replace `RANDOM_STRING` with `[^/]*`. And in a regex pattern, to match `.`, you need to use `\.`.

Comment: I want something simple, like `[^/]*`. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!

Comment: If `[^/]*` works for you why did you accept the answer below? Are you going to use the splitting approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a negated character class `[^/]` that matches any char but a `/`. So, replace `RANDOM_STRING` with `[^/]*`.

Also, in a regex pattern, to match `.`, you need to escape the dot - `\.`.

Thus, your regex pattern can be fixed as

```
(?<="href=""www\.example\.com/account/[^/]*/").*?(?="">)
```

However, you may user a simpler regex with a capturing group:

```
"href=""www\.example\.com/account/[^/]*/"(.*?)"">
```

The value you need is in `Match.Groups(1).Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Or another option would be to do this

```
 Dim strOne As String = "www.example.com/account/43210/king42"
 Dim strMain As String = Split(strOne, "/account/")(1)
 Dim strSubOne As String = Split(strMain, "/")(0)
 Dim strSubTwo As String = Split(strMain, "/")(1)
```